# with images and a wishes in grid view in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hello friends I m in trouble I use a asp.net with C# I want to show a grid for employees birthday so i want some designing like at the header of grid view show a cute image and a some slogan for birthday wish  after it name or birthday of employee so provide me some code for this functioning

Comment: no Code... No Fun... How to help if you don't put your code??

Comment: Search for how to examine the data on row bind in code behind and place a picture as needed.

Comment: thank dean i have no code for this that's why i m asking krunal

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you want to display it on the gridview ??
if yes, then wheres your data comes from ??
database (SQL,o) or static??